# Camel hump string split

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Given `System` names of 2 or more characters:

```
systemNames = Names["System`*"] // Select[StringLength[#] > 1 &] ;
```

Is there a more compact way to split at upper case letters that avoids the `Partition` and subsequent `StringJoin`?

EDIT: match to digits as well as upper case, but still w/ limitations outlined below:

```
systemNames // 
  Map[StringSplit[#, 
      x : c_ /; (UpperCaseQ[c] || DigitQ[c]) :> x] & /* (Partition[#, 2] & )] // 
 Map[Map[StringJoin]]
```

[image]

Also, what's the easiest way to also split at `$` and also the final upper case char, eg `N`? I coudn't find an easy way with `Alternatives` and longer `___`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do all of it directly with `StringCases`!

```
StringCases[systemNames, hump : (CharacterRange["A", "Z"] | DigitCharacter) | "$" ~~ restOfCamel : CharacterRange["a", "z"] ...]

(*
{{A,A,S,Triangle},{Abelian,Group},{Abort},{Abort,Kernels},{Abort,Protect},
{Above},{Abs}, ...5182... ,{$,User,Base,Directory},
{$,User,Documents,Directory},{$,User,Name},{$,Version},{$,Version,Number},
{$,Wolfram,I,D},{$,Wolfram,U,U,I,D}}
*)
```

And, out of pure envy, a version that **wrongly** groups abbreviations as suggested by @WReach!

```
StringCases[systemNames, hump : CharacterRange["A", "Z"] .. | "$" ~~ restOfCamel : CharacterRange["a", "z"] ...]

(*
{{AASTriangle},{Abelian,Group},{Abort},{Abort,Kernels},{Abort,Protect},{Above},
{Abs},{Absolute}, ...5185... ,{$,User,Base,Directory},
{$,User,Documents,Directory},{$,User,Name},{$,Version},{$,Version,Number},
{$,Wolfram,ID},{$,Wolfram,UUID}}
*)
```

<s>Just 2 dots of difference! Finally something that was easier to do with ordinary patterns instead of regexes!</s>  **Noooot.**

#### Finally

A version with ordinary patterns that does the marvels that @WReach`s look-ahead regexes can do. Two separate pattern "levels" must be used, though.

```
StringCases[systemNames, hump : (CharacterRange["A", "Z"] | DigitCharacter) | "$" ~~ restOfCamel : CharacterRange["a", "z"] ...]
Replace[%, {pre___, Longest[d1__?UpperCaseQ], post___} :> {pre, StringJoin@d1, post}, {1}]

(*
{{"AAS", "Triangle"}, {"Abelian", "Group"}, {"Abort"}, {"Abort", "Kernels"}, {"Abort", "Protect"},
{"Above"}, {"Abs"}, {"Absolute"}, ...5184... , {"$", "User", "Base", "Directory"},
{"$", "User", "Documents","Directory"}, {"$", "User", "Name"}, {"$", "Version"}, {"$", "Version", "Number"},
{"$", "Wolfram", "ID"}, {"$", "Wolfram", "UUID"}}
*)
```

And a quick fix for the `{Te,X}` issue

```
Replace[%, {pre___, "Te", "X", post___} :> {pre, "TeX", post}, {1}]
```

Comment: Alas, the two dots are not quite enough for the abbreviations.  Notice how "AASTriangle" is not split up.  It doesn't detract from a good answer, though.

Comment: Ohh, you are correct! I knew the "just 2 dots" would come back to bite me.

Comment: I give up, @WReach! Couldn't do it elegantly... I better learn myself some regex magic.

Comment: +1, I like the approach, but your method eats digits, "BarChart3D" -> {"Bar", "Chart", "D"}. My original method also requires matching to `DigitQ`. Can you modify yours?

Comment: There you go, @alancalvitti!

Comment: I also finally managed to mimic @WReach's in a reasonable way. You can now either have `{"Bar", "Chart", "3", "D"}` or `{"Bar", "Chart", "3D"}`.`{"$", "HTML", "Export", "Rules"}`, `{"$", "HTTP", "Cookies"}` are also "working", but `{TeX,...}` can only be found with exceptions on the rule.

Comment: @Aisamu, that's great. If you agree - and cite - my answer below, ie, if it helped you arrive at the final method, I'll accept your version.

Comment: I actually didn't have time to study your answer, @alancalvitti! Since you were the OP I considered the "TeX" issue an extension to the question, which I  upvoted!

Answer (score 12):

Here is a method using `StringSplit` and `RegularExpression`:

```
StringSplit[systemNames, RegularExpression["(?=[$[:upper:]])"]]

(*
   {{A,A,S,Triangle},{Abelian,Group},{Abort},{Abort,Kernels},{Abort,Protect},
    {Above},{Abs},<<5192>>,{$,User,Documents,Directory},{$,User,Name},{$,Version},
    {$,Version,Number},{$,Wolfram,I,D},{$,Wolfram,U,U,I,D}}
*)
```

It works by splitting each string wherever it finds a zero-length substring which is followed by a dollar sign or an upper case character.  `(?=...)` is the zero-length look-ahead syntax. `[$[:upper:]]` matches any character in the set comprised of the literal dollar sign along with all members of the upper case character class.

It might be interesting to keep groups of otherwise loose upper case letters together and treat them as abbreviations.  If so, then:

```
StringSplit[
  systemNames
, RegularExpression[
    "(?=\\$)|(?<![[:upper:]])(?=[[:upper:]])|(?=[[:upper:]][^[:upper:]])"
  ]
]

(*
   {{AAS,Triangle},{Abelian,Group},{Abort},{Abort,Kernels},{Abort,Protect},
    {Above},<<5191>>,{$,User,Name},{$,Version},{$,Version,Number},
        {$,Wolfram,ID},{$,Wolfram,UUID}}
*)
```

Note how "AAS" in the first entry and "UUID" in the last are kept together as abbreviations.  This pattern works by matching a dollar sign, or an upper case letter that is not preceded by another upper case letter, or an upper case letter followed by a non-uppercase letter.

**Edit: Including Digits as "Hump" Characters**

A comment requests that digits be treated as "hump" characters.  This is accomplished by changing each occurrence of the regular expression pattern `[[:upper:]]` to `[\\d[:upper:]]`.  `\\d` matches any digit character.

```
namesWithDigits = Select[systemNames, !StringFreeQ[#, DigitCharacter]&];

StringSplit[namesWithDigits, RegularExpression[#]]& @
    "(?=\\$)|(?<![\\d[:upper:]])(?=[\\d[:upper:]])|(?=[\\d[:upper:]][^\\d[:upper:]])"

(*
  {{Appell,F1},{Arrow,3D,Box},{Bar,Chart,3D},{Bezier,Curve,3D,Box},<<85>>,
   {Text,3D,Box},{Text,3D,Box,Options},{V2,Get},{Vector,Plot,3D}}
*)
```

Comment: Everyday you teach me something about regexes!

Comment: +1, Great, particularly the complication to handle AAS, UUID, and many more, which was the evental goal. Can you include matches to DigitQ? Currently: `"BarChart3D" -> {"Bar", "Chart3", "D"}`.

Comment: @WReach, Also, is `RegularExpression` necessary here? The syntax is cryptic. We need a more transparent and scalable approach going forward for advanced analytics, whether text or any other character encoded signal).

Comment: @alancalvitti See the new section concerning digit characters.  I'm afraid that the _Mathematica_ symbolic string pattern syntax does not yet fully support all of the functionality in PCRE regular expressions.  I agree that they are so cryptic as to be "write only".

Comment: How does it do for `JacobiCN` and `NDSolve`?

Answer (score 4):

Using insights from WReach and Aisamu here's a version with good properties on system names:

```
humpCharacters = 
  Flatten@{CharacterRange["A", "Z"], CharacterRange["0", "9"]};
```

.

```
StringSplit[systemNames, 
  c : humpCharacters ~~ 
    rest : Except[Append[humpCharacters, "$"]] .. :> c <> rest] // 
  Map[Select[# != "" &]]
```

From visual inspection of output (~5000 names) only the following issues are apparant:

```
(* "TeX" --> {"Te", "X", "Form"}, {"Te", "X", "Save"} 
   "$HTML", "$HTTP" --> {"$HTML", "Export", "Rules"}, {"$HTTP", "Cookies"}  *)
```

Comment: Guess I'll ask you too: how does it do for `JacobiCN` and `NDSolve`?

Comment: `{"JacobiCN", "NDSolve"} // Map@camelHumpStringSplit` --> `{{"Jacobi", "CN"}, {"ND", "Solve"}}`

Comment: Ah, so it treats the `ND` as a single unit. Thanks.

Comment: Could be modified though.

Comment: I suppose, but then it might screw up on `AASTriangle`; I guess the point I was trying to make is that with so many symbols these days, you're bound to have some inconsistencies. That reminds me: `MittagLefflerE` will be split in the expected way, even though the mathematician's surname is "Mittag-Leffler". :)

Comment: System names are a finite universe. Take a look at this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/organizing-wolfram-language-symbols-with-entity. Only a small number of exceptions to the naive method above fail. With prior info about the language, (eg use of `N` and `D`) some of those exeptions could be handled.