# Organizing Wolfram language symbols with Entity

Tags: symbols, built-in-symbols, entity

Here's a word cloud tally of the ~5k System names [split at camel humps](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66108/camel-hump-string-split), with the long tail cropped.

What resources are available to organize these terms using the new [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=entity) functionality? Applications might include:

- Retrieve related objects `Select[MatchQ[{___, "Graph"}]]` exceptions to camel hump model include: `HighlightGraph` is not a type of graph, `HermiteH` should be grouped with `Polynomial` entity. Is there a method to crowd-source tagging and linking? Or even automate discovery of such links (eg from documentation).
- Tree or graph visualization of related symbols.
- Highlight undocumented symbols.
- Compare `Attributes`.

EDIT:

By request, code to generate the word cloud. Note that I'm using my more compact method rather than Aisamu's foolproof, b/c they give basically the same result mod a few symbols.

```
names[in] = Names["System`*"] // Select[StringLength[#] > 1 &] ;

humpCharacters = 
  Flatten@{CharacterRange["A", "Z"], CharacterRange["0", "9"]}; 

names[data] = 
  names[in] // 
    AssociationMap[
     StringSplit[#, 
        c : humpCharacters ~~ 
          rest : Except[Append[humpCharacters, "$"]] .. :> 
         c <> rest] & /* Select[# != "" &]] // Dataset;

names[data][Catenate /* Tally /* SortBy[Last] /* Reverse][
  Map[Style[First[#], FontSize ->  (Last[#]/3 + 8)]^
    Style[Last[#], Red] &]] // Normal
```

[image]

Comment: Would you provide the code that produced this cloud tally?

Comment: @murray, sure, will add it.

Comment: @murray, appended word cloud method.

Comment: Have a look at V10.2's [WolframLanguageData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, this is good, thanks. Will need to test, eg there's many families of polynomials and then there's `HermiteH` which hopefully is a related entity despite no keywords in common.