# Automatically control size of slides in the SlideShow screen environment

Tags: slideshows

WRI says there is "no easy way" to control the aspect ratio of slides in slideshows, even though everything is an expression and there's [~200 kinds](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/organizing-wolfram-language-symbols-with-entity) of `Box`.

In other words, a slide grows as more content is added. That's less like a slide and more like a notebook. Is there a way to auto-resize the content or at least break to a new slide when the content reaches a certain size?

Comment: If you think the slide is getting too full it isn't that difficult to start a new one yourself, is it?

Comment: That's the wrong way to think. PowerPoint auto resizes. Like the Emerald ECL1 cloud lab's WL/SLL, we should aim for computational closure - on the UI.

Comment: That's the wrong way to design a slide, I'd say. Having slides with various font sizes is ugly and besides, it means you're cramming too much on a slide. The golden rule is: No more than 9 short lines on a slide.

Comment: Agreed in general, but WTC template is slides > https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2015/files/wtc-presentation-template.nb , so there's code + graphics as well as text. But even so, the elastic PPT bullet points are a great feature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has already been answered "no" by Wolfram Research